# Empty a column with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table1 that contain "id" "name" "city" I want to delete all text inside "city", but only text that are between "id" 17500 and 21000.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: This is fundamental SQL, your question almost reads like the actual query you would use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly basic SQL.

```
UPDATE table1 SET city='' WHERE id BETWEEN 17500 AND 21000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 SET city=''
WHERE id BETWEEN 17500 AND 21000
```

Comment: That'll delete the entire rows, not blank out the `city` data.